# If $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is the projection of the set $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, are $Q$ and $P$ the same set except for 1 dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Let $P$ denote a polyhderal set of $x$ values in $\mathbb{R}^n: \{x: Ax \leq b\}$. Let $Q$ denote the projection of $P$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (i.e., $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$).

Do the sets $P$ and $Q$ contain the same values of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$? That is, for $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in $P$, does $Q$ contain the same $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$? In other words, are $Q$ and $P$ the same set except for 1 dimension (the $n$th dimension)?

If so, is there a name of this property, or is this inherent in the definition of a projection?

Comment: I assume you're doing an orthogonal projection onto $Q$. No, there's no reason that dimension *must* collapse. This will happen only a points of $Q$ over which there's a one-dimensional set of points in $P$. But that certainly needn't be the case.

Comment: To get what you want, every face of $P$ would have to contain a line parallel to the $x_n$-axis, and that seems impossible. This will happen only when you take $P$ to be the preimage of a polyhedral set $Q$ under the projection map, it seems to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin. Under the assumption that both $P$ and $Q$ are polyhedral sets, where $Q$ is the projection of $P$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, are $Q$ and $P$ the same set except for the $n$th dimension? This is my question. I'm not completely sure If I understood your first comment.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood your question. Your question really doesn't make sense. There may be one point of $P$ or several or infinitely many above each point of $Q$. So what do you mean by "the same set"? Is the line $y=x+2$ the same as the $x$-axis except for the $y$-coordinate? Is the line $x=3$ in the plane the same as the point $x=3$ in the $x$-axis? You have no control over how many points there are above each point of $Q$. Think about a triangle with one edge parallel to the $y$-axis and what its projection will be.

Comment: @TedShifrin Suppose $P = \{x| Ax < b\}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $Q = \{x^*|Cx < d\}$, where $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Suppose that $Q$ is the projection of $P$. In this case, is $x_j = x^*_j$ for $j = 1, \ldots, n-1$? Sorry if my question is unclear.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me, either. What we know is that if $x^*$ is in $Q$, then there is *some* (perhaps infinitely many) $x\in P$ with the projection of $x$ equal to $x^*$. But you seem to be thinking of a one-to-one correspondence. That depends, as I said, on the precise shape of $P$. You seem to be thinking of a $P$ that lives in a hyperplane not containing the $x_n$-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common definition of "projection operator" is "idempotent operator".  This means that after projecting once, repeat projection does not move the point.

One problem with your statement "projecting onto $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$" is that you don't restrict to particular choices of $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$.  There are infinitely many choices of $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ as a (potentially affine) subspace in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$.  A projection to one of these subspaces needs to define which one is the image.

For instance, in the plane, one can project $(x,y)$ onto the line $x = 1$ by $(x,y) \mapsto (1,y)$.  Then the set of $y$-values is exactly preserved by this projection.  Notice that it isn't the first several coordinates that are preserved.  We could renumber our coordinates so that the leading coordinates were fixed and only the last coordinate was projected away, but we would have to say so.  (This is a variation of projection onto the second coordinate.  You should understand that there are projections onto any subset of the coordinates.  Almost all of these modify coordinates other than the last one.  In $\Bbb{R}^n$, there are $n$ choices of one coordinate to "forget" by projection onto a subset of the coordinates.  Only one of these preserves all but the last coordinate.)

Additionally, a projection need not be a coordinate projection.  Consider the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y+1,-1)$.  This map is idempotent, so is a projection.  None of the coordinates is preserved in this projection.

So the property you are wanting is "projection onto the first $n-1$ coordinates".  This means a map
$$  \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{n-1}: (x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Yes, that is the projection the OP is thinking of. But you haven't addressed the real issue (if you can decipher it) in the question. The question was not posed by a pedantic mathematician.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Whlie I agree that the question was not posed by a pedantic mathematician, it is very clear that what is asked is "are all one dimension down projections the 'project away the last coordinate' projection".  I've fully responded to that question.  This answer is literally the answer I have provided in face-to-face situations with real students whose ability to frame their question is limited.  I have no delusion that Questions are going to be Platonic Ideal Questions.

Comment: Perhaps I wasted too much time trying to decipher the question. I thought the OP wanted to recover $P$ from $Q$ or vice-versa. And, yes, I taught 40+ years … :)